# Emacs "Query replace regexp" Replaces with ALL CAPS

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

Using GNU Emacs 24.3.1, with the following text:

```
switch (input)
{
case ThisEnum::Type::UNDEFINED:
   UNDEFINED = 0,
   break;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Why does Emacs turn this

```
Query replace regexp (default \([[:alpha:]]*\) = .*,$ -> retval = ThatEnum::Type::\1;):
```

into this

```
Query replacing \([[:alpha:]]*\) = .*,$ with RETVAL = THATENUM::TYPE::UNDEFINED;: (? for help)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the consequence of `case-replace` being set to true (you can customize this variable).

If `case-replace` is true, Emacs tries to preserve original text case when replacing, if the pattern itself has no uppercase letters: replacement is upcased when the original happens to be ALL CAPS.